# Authentication between SharePoint O365 and external OData web service

Tags: web-services, authentication, bcs, external-content-type, adfs

We are using SharePoint Online (O365) with ADFS.  We are also building an on-premise OData web service to provide data into the cloud as an External Content Type.

We understand generally how to use the Secure Store and Windows Credentials for authentication.

Is it possible to pass our SAML authentication token (obtained from ADFS) through BCS to our local on-premise web service?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get the answer to this myself with respect to SharePoint Online.  I have read in several places that you can achieve claims forwarding by setting the Authentication Mode to PassThrough in your ECT definition.  I am a few days away from being able to prove this with an externally-accessible test service.  I would be interested in hearing from anyone who has done this because I can't find any examples out there.

Azure AD also has some great configuration capabilities for defining remote apps and how to authenticate, including claims mapping with custom claims that I could really use.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to connect that explicitly to the Target Application in BCS.  If I could, I'd have a lot more tools to work with.